# JSON Error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, json

I have a problem on my code:

Look my JSON:

```html
{ "informations": { "version": "1_0_1_ALPHA", "terms": "https://dev-time.eu/fr/", "update": "20/12/2018", "game": "bo4", "reponse": "success" } , "multiplayer": { "map_code": "mp_urban", "map": "Arcenal", "dlc": "0", "date": "Sortie du jeu" } }
```

My code (PHP):

```
<?php $maps_name = file_get_contents("https://dev-time.eu/api/api__callofduty?game=bo4&map=mp_urban&type=mp"); ?>
        <?php $parsed_map = json_decode($maps_name); ?>
        <?= var_dump($maps_name); ?>
        "<?= $parsed_map->{'informations'}->{'version'}; ?>"
```

My var_dump return:

```html
string(354) "{ "informations": { "version": "1_0_1_ALPHA", "terms": "https://dev-time.eu/fr/", "update": "20/12/2018", "game": "bo4", "reponse": "success" } , "multiplayer": { "map_code": "mp_jungle2", "map": "Jungle", "dlc": "0", "date": "Sortie du jeu" } }" "
```

[image]

Comment: This line 248 is <?= $parsed_map->{'informations'}->{'version'}; ?>

Comment: Remove the braces and quotes from that line, you don't need them. `$parsed_map->informations->version`

Comment: The json it's returning is invalid. When you run `json_last_error()`, you get 4, which is JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX. It works fine if you copy/paste, which makes me wonder if there's a bad character in there.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Are you generating the json, or another website? When using json_encode on `$maps_name`, you're getting a lot more control characters than you should

Comment: The JSON is mine (my website).

Comment: Can you show how you're creating it? I'd suggest creating an array then using json_encode instead of attempting to generate your own string.

Comment: @DevKilioZDev just set the header from where(your website) you're sending the json like `"Content-Type: application/json",`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lxzha9

Comment: That code does not show the json that has the `informations` property in it.

Comment: Here: http://prntscr.com/lxzje6

Comment: Oy, yeah. Create the whole thing as an array, then use json_encode on the array, instead of attempting to manually create your json string. Also follow Curious_Mind's suggestion to return the content-type as `application/json`.

Comment: @Curious_MInd after add ``"Content-Type: application/json"```, => http://prntscr.com/lxzkcr

Comment: Also, if you're not going to be outputting any text/html, you don't need to keep going in and out of the PHP blocks.

Comment: @DevKilioZDev see what i get when I try with postman client https://pasteboard.co/HSMkXU1.png and seems it is issue of `BOM`

Comment: Hey @DevKilioZDev just remove the content type now and let me try again with your old code

Comment: It's good @Curious_MInd

Comment: @DevKilioZDev See my edited answer, It is working now after removing the BOM characters and if that helps fell free to upvote and accept it :)

Comment: YESS ! THANK YOU !

Comment: @DevKilioZDev finally it works, I was 20m+ with this issue, cheers mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the life savior for you** :)

```
 function remove_utf8_bom($str)
 {
    $bom_char = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    return preg_replace("/^$bom_char/", '', $str);
  }
```

**Full Working code** with `CURL`, `file_get_contents()` will also work

```
<?php
function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://dev-time.eu/api/api__callofduty?game=bo4&map=mp_urban&type=mp",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $response = remove_utf8_bom($response);   
}
$d = json_decode($response);
echo $d->informations->version;
?>
```